# PyQt5 Drag and Drop between Widgets

Tags: python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently trying to achieve something that seems relatively simple. There is a great example on dragging and dropping found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_drag_and_drop.htm).

Here is a class that I call card:

```
class Card(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, png_file):
        super(Card, self).__init__()
        self.pix_map = QPixmap(png_file)
        self.pix_map = self.pix_map.scaled(100, 140)
        self.setPixmap(self.pix_map)

        # self.setDragEnabled(True)
```

All this does is create a QLabel with an image of a specific size with an image attached to it.

I then place these cards in two instances of the following Card_Holder Widget like so:

```
class Card_Holder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        # Create Layout
        self.lay = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

        # Create Cards
        c1 = Card("Card1.jpg")
        c2 = Card("Card2.jpg")

        # Add Cards
        self.lay.addWidget(c1, 0, 0)
        self.lay.addWidget(c2, 3, 0)

        # Drag and Drop
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
```

What I would like to do is drag cards between each of the Card_Holder. So I added the `setAcceptDrops` to the Card_Holder just like the example tutorial.

The only problem I have is adding `setDragEnabled(True)` to the `Card` class. That completely debunks following the tutorial above. While `QLineEdit` contains functionality for dragging, a `QLabel` does not.

My question really comes down to this:

- Are there any any available QWidgets that allow for dragging or am I stuck with what I have?

Comment: I didn't really understand the problem. You want to be able to drag and drop Card objects across different positions of the QGridLayout?

Comment: Yes, as well as between two instances of the Card_Holder class.

Comment: any solutions ? author? I am hvaing same problem

Comment: Hi @Nimish, it has been quite some time. I may have combined the two classes such that the Cards were embedded within a `Card_Holder` class of which only 1 card can be held in a card holder. And then the user could drag the card/card_holder class in and out of a `card_stack` (this stack would accept drops).

Comment: if you find a sufficient answer, do post the solution here for others to see in the future

Comment: @Max Can you share the code.I didn't understood you completely

Comment: Our doubt is similar I suppose. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755369/drag-event-for-pyqt5-label-or-qpushbutton

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the code. But what I mean is to place the QLabel class within another class that has capability to use `self.setDragEnabled(True)`